# Alternative to OAuth 2.0 ROPC without interpreting HTML/Javascript

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm in the context of an embedded devices that uses an HTTPS client to request an access token on behalf of a user (delegated permission needed for the app).

I'm currently using OAuth 2.0 ROPC (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to get my token and everything works fine.

But since this authentication is deprecated I'd like to change to a more secure solution that works in hybrid identity federation scenarios.

I see that many other solutions exists, but I can't find one that doesn't need to interpret an HTML/JS response.

Here a CURL example to explain my point:

ROPC request:

```
curl -X POST "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token" --data "grant_type=password&scope=EWS.AccessAsUser.All&username=<username>&password=<password>&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Response:
`{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"ext_expires_in":3599,"access_token":"eyJ0eX....1234"}`

Here I can extract the token directly from the response.

But using other ways to get delegated permission token such as OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant flow (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow), responses are always an HTML that I can't interpret.

So here I am wondering if there is a solution to this situation.

Thanks in advance,
Aloïs KYROU

Comment: Have you tried requesting that url in your browser?

Comment: Hello Carl, it is not an URL but the entire content of an HTML page. I didn't try to run it on a browser tho since It wouldn't be a possible solution for my embedded device.

Comment: I'm talking about implicit flow request url.

Comment: Didn’t you say that the response is HTML, not a token?

Comment: The implicit flow can only obtain the token in the browser, because the flow is often used in single-page applications.

Comment: The other is to use interactive login auth code flow, but this still requires you to log in to the browser to obtain the authorization code, and then redeem the token in the background.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the implicit flow to obtain the token in the tool, you can only run the request url in the browser. Because using the implicit flow requires you to log in. Please note that before this, you must enable **id token** and **access token**.

[image]

Request the id token and access token in the browser.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client id}
&response_type=id_token token
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&scope=openid EWS.AccessAsUser.All
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, therefore if I can't log in in a browser so I can't use this flow. The "device flow" is not an option for my embedded solution (It doesn't work for us because we need the authentication process to be without external interraction after first configuration). Is there any other way to achieve my purpose ?

Comment: @A.KYROU  Yes, if you cannot log in to the browser, obviously this flow is not suitable for you.

Comment: @A.KYROU  Do you have to log in as a user?

Comment: Thanks again for your time ! Yes we need user permission because we are using the presence API from Graph. With ROPC it works because we handle the authentication process with only url-encoded requests and JSON parsing of the response. I see device flow is kinda thought for the purpose of embedded devices without keyboard but we need a way to authenticate from a pre establish configuration without user interaction after the first time. 
In ROPC user gives its username and password and we can handle the process for each new token without him interracting again since we saved its credentials.

Comment: @A.KYROU  According to you, I think only ROPC flow is suitable for you.

Comment: OK thanks for your answers Carl, at least I'm not missing a simple solution. I thought this situation could happen a lot where people want access to API with user permission to build embedded based on Graph API. But we already have trouble with clients that have secure network that disable ROPC flow...

Comment: @A.KYROU  If you want to obtain a user token (that is, delegated permissions), there are only two authentication flows, one is interactive login (through a browser), and the other is silent login (ROPC flow).  And what you are currently using is to hard-code the user name and password into your back-end code, and you cannot log in the user interactively in the browser.  So, I think your problem may not be solved. Unless you modify the code so that the user can log in in the browser.